# Adjust all worksheets with the same layout

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to remove unwanted lines off all the worksheets. For example:
I have multiples worksheets that I need to make a treatment that consist on finding a special character like "-" and remove everything that is above that line, and I mean exclude all lines.

I'm stuck now.. I can't do it properly to apply to all my worksheets and the cell range is different each day.

So far I could do..

```
Sub Clean()
'
' Clean Macro
'

'
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1.txt").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1.txt").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key _
        :=Range("A1:A66723"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1.txt").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="-", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range("A59044").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: So, in column A, you want to find a cell with only `-`, and then delete all rows above it? Then repeat for all worksheets in a workbook?

Comment: Like @BruceWayne I'm not completely sure what it is that you are looking for. But if I understand your issue, here are a couple of things that might help: have a look at `offset` and also how to dynamically get the last row in your worksheet

Comment: Yes.
I need to find in A column and repeat to all worksheets.@BruceWayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub Clean()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Search As Range
    Dim addr As String

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Activate

        With ws.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Cells
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With


        With ws.Range("A:A")
            Set Search = .Find(What:="-", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

            If Not Search Is Nothing Then
                addr = Search.Address
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With

        Range(addr).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: >Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)

Comment: Can you Debug your code and see in what line the error is showing up? But I'm thinking the error is in the "underline" marks. Try removing them, and put the sentence in a single line. @ARGC

Comment: The line is showing up now is:
Selection.Find(What:="-", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Comment: I changed it again. The both code worked very well around here. @ARGC

Comment: Didn't work. I run and it deleted all the other data. The macro just kept the data I didn't want xD @Rafael Matos

Comment: Are you sure it is the data that you want? You said that you want to remove all the data above the "-" character. And that is what this code is doing. @ARGC

Comment: Sorry, I meant below.. English is a little bit outdated.

Comment: I changed it again. @ARGC

Comment: That's just perfect! Thank you!